# how to get values of variable which is taken from array?

Tags: shell

How to get the value of variable which is taken from array,

```
iparray=("ip1" "ip2" "ip3")
ip2=127.0.0.1
ip2=127.0.0.2
ip2=127.0.0.3


for ips in ${iparray[@]}; do
for value in $ips; do
    echo $ips $value
done
done
```

am getting output like below

```
ip1 ip1
ip2 ip2
ip3 ip3
```

but i need output like below

```
ip1 127.0.0.1
ip2 127.0.0.2
ip3 127.0.0.3
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could put the ip addresses in an associative array and use the key to access the address:

```
iparray=("ip1" "ip2" "ip3")
declare -A ip

ip[ip1]=127.0.0.1
ip[ip2]=127.0.0.2
ip[ip3]=127.0.0.3

for ips in ${iparray[@]}; do
    echo $ips ${ip[$ips]}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variable variables case.
In bash, you can use ${!variable} to deal with it.

Modify your for loop to,

```
for ips in ${iparray[@]}; do
    echo $ips ${!ips}
done
```

The output would be:

```
ip1 127.0.0.1
ip2 127.0.0.2
ip3 127.0.0.3
```